# Smaller than or bigger than shows wrong result

Tags: javascript

I have this small piece of code:

```
if(parseFloat(400).toFixed(2) < parseFloat(21233).toFixed(2)){
//Cant Do It
} else {
//Can Do It
}
```

How it makes sense? 400 IS smaller than 21233, but regarding to this code it isn't like this. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toFixed()` outputs a *string* so you're comparing:

```
"400.00" < "21233.00"
```

Which is `false` because `"4"` is not less than `"2"`.

Comment: Is there other solution changing toFixed? So It won't give out string.

Comment: @Jordn simply dont do 'toFixed' , as *+a.toFixed(2)>+b.toFixed(2)* is always the same as *a>b*

Comment: @Jordn your input is integers so you can compare them directly. If your input is string you can do `Math.round(parseFloat("400") * 100)` to get an int with 2 decimals of precision.